# How to make an object its own delegate while still allowing others to be its delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I want to create a new class, MYTableView which inherits from UITableView. MYTableView will have an NSArray property that stores all of its data. This means I no longer have to worry about implementing `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow`, because MYTableView will be its own datasource and provide the necessary data. Additionally, I want MYTableView to have some custom logic in the `didSelectRow` method, so I set it up to be its own delegate as well.

Now here is the problem... I have a TVC (a UITableViewController) object which has a MYTableView instance. I want to override the logic in the `didSelectRow` method. That is, I want the logic from MYTableView to happen in addition to TVC's logic.

**Solution 1:** `tableView.delegate = TVC`
Obviously this won't work. If I try to set the tableView's delegate back to the TVC, then yes, the TVC's didSelectRow method is called, but then the MYTableView's logic is never called, because we hijacked the delegate.

**Solution 2:** `tableView.delegate2 = TVC`
I could create a second delegate (see code below) and set TVC to be the delegate2. I would then call delegate2's didSelectRow method from within the tableView.delegate's didSelectRow method.

Problems:

- Having `delegate` and `delegate2` is ugly. Additionally, if the user sets delegate to be something else, things break.
- I would have to forward every single event that TVC might want to implement.

**Questions:**

Since this is not an optimal solution. Can you think of any better solutions?

If I have no control over the inherited class (e.g. if I am inheriting from UITableView), what are my options?

If I do have control over the inherited class (e.g. I am using a hypothetical UITableView of which I own the source code to), what would be the best way to implement it to allow this sort of functionality?

Notes:

- The `didSelectRow` currently only has 1 line of code in these examples. Obviously if it was only one line of code, then this wouldn't be a big problem, I would find a way around it. The real code is many lines of code.

### Full code follows: (for solution 2)

```
// ---------------------------------------------------
// VC.m
// ---------------------------------------------------

@implementation VC

- (MYTableView *)myTableView {
    return (MYTableView *)self.tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.myTableView.delegate2 = self;
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    static NSInteger i = 0;
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        [self.myTableView insertObject:[NSNull null] inDataArrayAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        [self.myTableView insertObject:[NSDate date] inDataArrayAtIndex:0];
    }
    i++;
}

#pragma mark - MYTableViewDelegate

- (void)myTableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Selected row: %@", indexPath);
}

@end


// ---------------------------------------------------
// MYTableView.h
// ---------------------------------------------------

@class MYTableView;

@protocol MYTableViewDelegate <UITableViewDelegate>
@optional
- (void)myTableView:(MYTableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@interface MYTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MYTableViewDelegate> delegate2;
- (void)insertObject:(NSObject *)object inDataArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

// ---------------------------------------------------
// MYTableView.m
// ---------------------------------------------------

@interface MYTableView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@end

@implementation MYTableView

- (void)commonInit {
    self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)insertObject:(NSObject *)object inDataArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [self.dataArray insertObject:object atIndex:index];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString * const identifier = @"String Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray[indexPath.row] description];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSObject *object = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    if ([NSNull null] == object) {
        [self deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    if ([self.delegate2 respondsToSelector:@selector(myTableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
        [self.delegate2 myTableView:self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two delegates, but override the setDelegate method to make things at least appear cleaner.  I've done something similar in a subclass of UITextView: https://github.com/mbachrach/GCPTextView

Comment: Interesting solution, one drawback I see is that if you forget to forward a delegate method (or if Apple introduces a new delegate method and you haven't updated the subclass yet), the external delegate won't get called.

Answer (score 0):

What if you made a separate class that just implements the UITableViewDataSource protocol based on your datasource. This can be an NSObject or I suppose your MyTableView if you really want to do it that way. It is a very highly reusable class which will make your life easier in the future.

As for the double delegate problem, what if you handled the selection of the row through UITableViewDelegate in MyTableView but setup a block-based system for selecting the view controller.

```
void(^RowSelected)(void)(NSObject *selectedObject, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Fixing UITextView on iOS 7](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2014/fixing-uitextview-on-ios-7/), the author mentions that he [automatically forwards all delegate methods](https://github.com/steipete/PSPDFTextView/blob/ee9ce04ad04217efe0bc84d67f3895a34252d37c/PSPDFTextView/PSPDFTextView.m#L148-164) in the source code for PSPDFTextView.

He accomplishes this by doing the following:

1. Set yourself up as the delegate by calling `[super setDelegate:self]`.
2. Override `setDelegate:` to capture the external delegate in a property called `realDelegate`.
3. In any delegate methods you implement, forward them to the `realDelegate` (if it responds to that selector):

   ```
   - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
       id<UITextViewDelegate> delegate = self.realDelegate;
       if ([delegate respondsToSelector:_cmd]) {
           [delegate textViewDidBeginEditing:textView];
       }

       // custom code goes here
   }
   ```
4. Implement `respondsToSelector:`, `methodSignatureForSelector:`, and `forwardInvocation:` to forward the rest of the methods:

   ```
   - (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
       return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector] || [self.realDelegate respondsToSelector:aSelector];
   }

   - (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
       return [super methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector] ?: [(id)self.realDelegate methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
   }

   - (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
       id delegate = self.realDelegate;
       if ([delegate respondsToSelector:anInvocation.selector]) {
           [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:delegate];
       }
   }
   ```

One drawback to this method is that **it will forward *any* call to realDelegate**; not just those that are implemented in UITextFieldDelegate. For example, if your delegate is a UIViewController and you execute the following code:

```
self.textView.delegate = self;
[(id)self.textView viewDidLoad];
```

You would ideally want it to crash (since your UITextView subclass does not implement `viewDidLoad`). However, because *any* method called on the subclass will be forwarded to the delegate, the text view will see that it doesn't know how to handle viewDidLoad, so then it will ask the delegate; the delegate will report that it does know how to execute this code, and so it will call the delegate's viewDidLoad method!